# Is kotlin language production ready for my news codename one' s projects?

Tags: codenameone

Searching on Stack overflow I found other question about this subject,
but the ansewers provided  are  obsolete. The last update was in july 2017.

My  question is a little bit different . My concerns are about the maturity of kotlin's support.

After Plugin 4.0, do the old answers remains valid?
Is kotlin  production ready?
Is reliable to use kotlin for my new projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wanted to graduate Kotlin out of beta with 4.0 but we decided to do that in 5.0.

We are currently aware of one large app that was ported from Android Kotlin to Codename One and now runs on iOS: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/max2math/id1363509690

There might be more because we can't "see" what language is used under the hood.

Notice that in this case the port was hard as the starting point was Kotlin Android code which is pretty different from Codename One code. If you start from scratch this should be better.

The Kotlin support is inherently less mature as Codename One built thousands of apps in Java over 10 years... But we think it should be stable enough for a production app.